# Failing in allowing requests from an IP access to Nginx without supplying credentials

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to implement *Nginx whitelisting*, namely to allow users - coming from a certain IP address - access to Nginx without supplying credentials.
However, even though I followed the [Nginx documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/), requests coming from a browser on that IP are challenged for *username/password* (401 Authentication Required).

That's my configuration (on AWS/EC2 CentOS 7 instance):

```
[centos@ip-172-31-94-4 nginx]$ cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        satisfy all; 

        # Requests from this IP need not supply a password
        allow 96.53.xx.xx;
        deny all;

        # Others should supply username/passwords
        auth_basic           "Private site";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Can you suggest how to make Nginx requests coming from 96.53.xx.xx pass through without being challenged for *username/password*?

Edit:
Browser cache and history were cleared, and `sudo nginx -s reload` executed.

Answer (score 0):

After changing `satisfy all` to `satisfy any`, the whitelisting seems to be working.